# List<T>.AddRange / InsertRange creating temporary array

Tags: c#

While looking at the Implementation of List.AddRange i found something odd i do not understand.
[Sourcecode, see line 727](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,727) (AddRange calls InsertRange)

```
T[] itemsToInsert = new T[count];
c.CopyTo(itemsToInsert, 0);
itemsToInsert.CopyTo(_items, index);
```

Why doest it Copy the collection into a "temp-array" (itemsToInsert) first and then copies the temp array into the actual _items-array?
Is there any reason behind this, or is this just some leftover from copying ArrayList's source, because the same thing happens there.

Comment: I would assume it's to pass items through by value instead of by reference so that the original items being inserted are not modified in the event that the items within the list themselves are modified

Comment: @Jdsfighter - I don't see how that helps at all. The contents of an array or a collection are either values or references. The above code does nothing to change the nature of what's being copied.

Comment: I don't really think that it's to hide the underlying array. In my answer i pointed other probable explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that this is to hide the existence of the internal backing array. There is no way to obtain a reference to that array which is intentional. The `List` class does not even promise that there is such an array. (Of course, for performance and for compatibility reasons it will always be implemented with an array.)

Someone could pass in a crafted `ICollection<T>` that remembers the array that it is passed. Now callers can mess with the internal array of `List` and start depending on `List` internals.

Contrast this with `MemoryStream` which has a documented way to access the internal buffer (and shoot yourself with it): `GetBuffer()`.

Comment: If this is the actual reason then I don't really see the point: someone could also use reflection to look for private array fields if they want to mess with things.

Comment: Using reflection you can pry anything open but that's harder and happens more rarely in practice. This appears to be protection against accidental or careless API misuse. Calling code invariably starts to depend on invariants that happen to be true right now but are not guaranteed. The harder this is the more rare it will be.

Comment: Crafting a collection that remembers arrays with the intention of messing with internals isn't much more common, I'd say. Same intention really, and not something that I think is worth protecting against in a general-purpose library. EDIT: I see, this does protect against certain accidental misuse. Not that far-fetched after all given how much List is used.

Comment: I see your point. Easiest misuse would be a mistake with a for-loop that does something like this target[i+index] = myValue[i]....

Comment: Also it closes the only gap to access the internal array using supported means. InsertRange with collections is a rarely used API anyway. I find myself rarely manipulating lists for some reason except calling Add.